# How can I plot a whole scaled data set with one line per row?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data set with 6 alternatives. I used the `scale` function to  standardize my data set. Now I want to plot a curve for each row.

I want to have my six alternatives as values in the X-Axis, and their standardize value in the Y-Axis.

A sample of my data set is like this:

```
    fish   rice   meet   milk

   1   2.3    3.4   1.4     1.3
   1   2.6    3.5   2.4     2.4
   1   4.3    1.9   3.3     3.1
   1  1.3    2.4   4.4     9.3
   2  1.3    3.4   4.1     3.4
   2   3.3    2.9   3.3     2.1
   2   4.5    3.9   3.3     3.1
   2  1.4    2.4   4.4     9.3
```

where first column is individual, in this sample we had 2 person
Now I want to draw a curve for each row so in the x-axis I have (fish, rice meet milk) and in y-axis I have these numbers.

For example, the first curve is formed by connecting points   2.3, 3.4, 1.4, 1.3 in y-axis

Comment: Please [edit your question as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please read the above and do edit as users suggested. You can simply read the accepted answer on there.

Comment: I think you should `reshape` your data first from wide to long. It almost always makes life easier.

Comment: it is already in long shape

Comment: It's actually wide although in this case reshaping might be inappropriate.

Comment: How does that new variable you just added change anything? You still say you want 1 line per row and don't mention how to use "individual"

Comment: *six alternatives*? I am seeing 8. try `matplot(t(data), type = 'l')`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want each row to be a separate group, you should make row number a variable to preserve that information, then reshape the data from wide to long so you can plot it properly in ggplot2:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = df %>%
    rowid_to_column('row') %>%
    gather(key, value, -row)

head(df1)
  row  key value
1   1 fish   2.3
2   2 fish   2.6
3   3 fish   4.3
4   4 fish   1.3
5   1 rice   3.4
6   2 rice   3.5

# group is needed to tell ggplot which points to connect in each line

ggplot(df1, aes(x = key, y = value, color = factor(row), group = row))  +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error : Error in TravelMode1 %>% rowid_to_column("row") %>% gather(key, value,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Did you properly load the tidyverse packages? `%>%` is in `dplyr` which will be loaded by `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Did they load correctly? That error means that `dplyr` wasn't attached properly. Try `library(dplyr)` and make sure it _actually_ attached without errors

Comment: Try restarting R and reinstalling the packages.